# Use TFS like File History?

Tags: tfs

I'm a solo developer working at home; I've just rolled out a new server and domain for myself using WSE 2012 R2 (Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials Edition). Unfortunately I've run into some conflicts.

As it turns out, OneDrive doesn't support Roaming Profiles. To make matters worse, File History doesn't support Folder Redirection. So it seems I have to choose between OneDrive and File History. OneDrive is about to win out, but I have an unresolved concern.

Just about the only thing I've ever used File History for is to retrieve snippets of prior versions of code. I rarely work up a spreadsheet and even less often do any word processing. So if TFS can act as a File History of sorts, I should be OK.

Trouble is...  I've never used TFS before (yet). I have no idea what the user interface even looks like, let alone how to get around in it. In fact the drive behind this server move has been my need for a TFS/Build implementation. Now, on the way, I find myself having to make this decision.

So. Will I be able to use TFS to locate and open for review (without replacing current) a single checked-in code file from, say, a given day two months prior?

Comment: What is this "WSE 2012 R2"? Do you mean Windows Server 2012 R2?

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials Edition (WSE for short). FYI I'll be installing TFS on a different VM, if that makes a difference toward the question.

Comment: Thanks. It's just that "WSE" is also the abbreviation for the obsolete "Web Services Extensions", so I wanted to make sure there was no "2012" version of that. I'm glad to find some other product taking over the abbreviation.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: FWIW, I decided to go with OneDrive/Redirection. If it gets so bad that I can't get previous versions from TFS I'll write my own somethin' to do the job.

Comment: I'm getting the impression that you don't have a lot of experience with source control.  Source control **is** "file history". Use real source control. Even if you think it's overkill for what you're doing (it really isn't), it's an industry standard practice and will be useful for the day you become a not-so-solo developer. Not being familiar with source control could potentially cost you jobs down the line. It's like saying that you're a carpenter, but you're not familiar with how hammers work.

Comment: @DanielMann: You've captured my sentiments exactly! You're exactly correct. Thank you for saying what I didn't want to :-)

Comment: @DanielMann: "... it's an industry standard practice ... useful for the day you become a not-so-solo developer." Yes, I'm painfully aware, thank you. Which is precisely why I'm trying to play catch-up. Your advice/assistance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the question "Will I be able to use TFS to locate and open for review (without replacing current) a single checked-in code file from, say, a given day two months prior?"

Yes, absolutely. You can also easily the changes between your current version and the file from 2 months ago.

You have two choices of source control. TFVC and Git. For a single developer, I'd suggest git is probably your better choice. You work locally with full source history, and regularly push your changes to VSO on regular basis to ensure your code is backed up. Of course, over time you could add an automated build using your VSO account to ensure you haven't forgotten to check anything in and to avoid the "works on my machine" problem.

Some links for you:

- [MSDN articles for TFVC file history](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181413.aspx)
- [A post on the VSO site with some screenshots](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-au/news/2012-dec-10-vso)
- [MSDN article for git file history](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn237244.aspx) (with pictures!)

Comment: Thanks for the links and the tips! I've decided to pass on VSO, though—I don't have a lot of faith in the notion of 99.999% network uptime. All it'll take is a brief outage and I'm out of business for the duration. I just can't afford that.

Comment: Another thing... I have a very strong desire to automate my builds and push them out to various staging platforms (testing VMs). Granted I haven't done any source control work in all of these twenty-five years—True!—but from everything I'm seeing it sounds like a local TFS implementation (running on a VM on my new T110 II) is going to be best approach for all of this.

Comment: @InteXX You are incorrect. Git is distributed version control -- you have a repo hosted in VSO, and then a clone of that repo locally. You can perform 100% of the version control operations (committing, investigating history, branching, merging) **offline**. You only need to be connected to VSO when you push your changes up to VSO.

Comment: Beyond that, you're scared of VSO having "99.999%" uptime. Your laptop, over time, has significantly lower uptime. All it will take is an accidental coffee spill or drive failure to wipe out your work. Use VSO.

Comment: @DanielMann: I have backup. But never mind. Do you have any links to a beginner's reference—for someone who's not yet used source control—describing how to set all this up? Especially the Git part? Also, what do I stand to gain/lose by going with Git vs. TFS or vice versa?

Comment: @DanielMann: My laptop doesn't have the resources required to run the amount of VMs necessary for the build/staging cycle. I need the server.

Comment: @DanielMann: It's a combination of factors. See my comment to MrHinsh below.

Comment: @DanielMann: Ah, I just remembered another one. I'm very interested in the Urban Turtle TFS add-on, which (so far) doesn't work with VSO.

Comment: VSO has build and release capabilities as well. Urban Turtle I can't help you with.

Comment: @DanielMann: You admonished me—even had the chutzpa to call me "scared"—for not using VSO. Well, after today's first foray into doing something as simple as creating a couple of projects and adding users, I can confidently say that I'll _never_ tie the success of my business on a loser like VSO. Click-and-wait, click-and-wait. Server response time is HORRIBLE. If I have to go to a little extra trouble to set up my own TFS, so be it. At least I'll have something under my control and responsive. No to VSO.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on why you recommend Git over TFVC?

Comment: @InteXX Git provides more flexibility in terms of developer workflows, gives you a full version control system on your local machine, and is extremely quick. Beyond that, it's too broad a subject to cover in a comment.

Comment: Thanks, that gives me something to go on.

Answer (score 0):

Do not create your own local TFS. You would be better using the Visual Studio Online (TFS Online) offering as it would be easyer to manage and maintain.

Comment: "Do not create your own local TFS." Alas, I must. I'm holed up in a cabin in the woods deep in the heart of Alaska. Internet is spotty—and slow when it does work. Also... I don't have full trust in so-called 'cloud' providers to keep their services available at any and every moment that I may need them. All of this translates into a local TFS, I'm afraid. (And I need the server for other reasons as well.)

Comment: I've just discovered that I'm far better off to install an on-premises TFS. I gave VSO a first test-run today and the results were abysmal. Server response times were simply unacceptable. Even considering the possibility that I happened to catch them at a rare bad moment, I'm left with a distinct impression that VSO doesn't present a safe foothold on which to pin the fate of my business.

Comment: @RichardBanks: Time is also money; if today's results are any reliable indicator, I'm better off financially to run my own in-house TFS.

Comment: Fair enough... if your internet is that spotty and slow then you must run local. However may bigger companies than you have bet hundreds of millions on cloud hardware and your business is FAR, and i do mean FAR, safer in the cloud than on some hardware that you run... if you have good internet...

Comment: FWIW I've long heeded the so-called "last mile problem," with regard to online services (the name 'cloud' bugs me for some reason). If a company puts mission critical operations on a remote server and something goes wrong amidst the thousands of moving parts between it and the server, that company is out of business for the duration. I just don't see it.

Comment: Would you care to engage a polite private conversation on the question? I'd like to try to read your mind a bit. My best email address can be found at my website, intexx.com.